# Argument error when testing code on repl.it

Tags: ruby

All my lessons have said that I can create any class I want.
Alas - I can't create a Taco class, even though it's formatted exactly like a Person class. Why do I get no taco?

```
class Taco
end

crispy = Taco.new



class Person
end

person = Person.new
```

The error is:

```
(eval):568: (eval):568:in initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError) from (eval):568:in new' from (eval):568
```

I am testing my code on http://repl.it

Comment: This looks fine to me. What error are you seeing?

Comment: (eval):568: (eval):568:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
 from (eval):568:in `new'
 from (eval):568

Comment: Works for me - are you posting the entire class?

Comment: What you see on the screen above is everything I typed into repl.it. I get no errors in irb though...

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ repl.it but have you been playing around w/ this for a while? If you previously defined a `Taco` class w/ an `initialize` method that takes one argument that would explain the the error you are seeing. The `Taco` class definition you currently have would not override the `initialize` that already exists.

Comment: I think it's a firefox bug. I had initialize methods and attr_accessors and everything. Then when things started failing I stripped down the class to the bare state you see it now.

Comment: I'd highly recommend relying on the command-line to test your code, rather than a website. Ruby is a command-line scripting language; Running it will involve their code sending it to the same thing you'd have to have running anyway, so cut out the middle man and use IRB or `ruby -cwW2 your_script.rb` at the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bug between http://repl.it and your browser. This works for me in Chrome on OS X. By the way, thanks for the pointer to [repl.it](http://repl.it). Here's what my screen looks like:

[image: repl.it screenshot]

The repl.it page does say that the Ruby interpreter is in beta.

Comment: it's crazy. When I use http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace, there are no errors either. These things should not happen to a newbie.

Comment: Welcome to computer programming. The randomness and frustration factors turn a lot of people away from the field. And correspondingly, they make those of us who stick with it more valuable.